# java -jar is not able to read classpath from manifest file resulting in NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: java, classpath, manifest, manifest.mf, maven-jar-plugin

My MANIFEST.MF file looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uwjbbQgX)

My main() prints the classpath -

```
  ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }
```

I am running jar file as-

```
java -jar "C:\Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

When I run the jar file, I don't see any of the class paths set in manifest file. I only see the absolute path to `C:\Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.  Why is that so? Obviously code fails to run due to `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error

Note that I am using `maven-jar-plugin` to create this jar file

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have line break at the end of the last line in your manifest file. If not then add a line break after the last line of Manifest.mf

Comment: @user375868 Are you sure dependency-jars in the path for the jars is working? Try to put the absolute path.

Comment: The issue is that "Class-Path" mentioned in manifest is not being read when I run through java -jar.

Comment: @user375868 I think the issue is that the path is not correct or generic to be referred from anywhere. When you use java -jar it will not understand the dependency-jars/xxx.jar path, which is related to maven. So you need to update the manifest to provide the path, which can be referred by java properly. Hence i said in my previous comment that try to give the absolute path of the jars in your manifest classpath variable.

Comment: I am following this example- http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/ - it should work, right?

Comment: @user375868 so when you explode your jar, do you have the jars mentioned in your classpath under the directory dependency-jars?

Comment: of course! see, the issue is class path is not being read from manifest file, if it was, my code in main would have printed it

Comment: What are the contents of the Manifest file?